# Assign different Hostname to different NIC

Tags: linux, redhat, ip, linux-networking

I have four network card on my server, I have assigned each with an specific IP now I want to set an different `hostname` for all the interface?

What is the difference between setting the `hostname` in file `/etc/sysconfig/network` or `/etc/hosts`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network` is where RHEL (and derivatives such as CentOS) set the  hostname/nodename that you'll see reflected on for instance the prompt of your shell, in system and log messages etc. That is the hostname that will be returned by the `gethostname(2)` and `uname` system calls.

A system only has **one hostname/nodename**, but it can have **many interfaces**.

You can point unlimited hostnames (or rather DNS names) to each interface, each ip-address. A many-to-one relationship.

The reverse mapping from ip-address to DNS name is one-to-one.  A reverse DNS lookup (using a PTR record or the same using /etc/hosts) will only return one name.

The `/etc/hosts` file is simply a local lookup table mapping ip-adresses to hostnames and the reverse. If you have a functional DNS server that will often be easier to maintain that rather then keeping many hosts files on different systems in sync.

Some network services will start slowly, fail  and/or give warnings if they can not resolve the hostname to an ip-address. (i.e. when being started in single user mode or when DNS fails to respond) so it is not uncommon to see /etc/hosts contains a reference to the hostname as well.

Often the `/etc/hosts` entry takes precedence over DNS allowing you to locally do "interesting" things.